# With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSummaryInfo) only work once

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this VBA script that forces Word to promt the user with a sugested filename when closing the file.

```
Sub NewTitle()
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSummaryInfo)
        .Title = "My_title"
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

It works fine the first time, but if the file has been saved once it doesn't work anymore.
Why is that, and what can be done about it?

BR Kresten

Comment: Word only uses the Title property, or the first line of the document, as a suggested filename on an unsaved document. Once the file has been saved it has a filename, so there is no longer any point in Word suggesting one.

Comment: Can't you force it to do so?

Comment: What do you want to force it to do, and under what circumstances? Please use the edit link under your question to explain what your overall goal is.

Comment: So far I've handled it with an event
 Private Sub Document_Close()
    ThisDocument.SaveAs2 "Path"
End Sub
That works no matter the saved state

Comment: I hope you've given the user the option to close without saving the changes.